# dask dataframe column renames are slow(er) when read from parquet

Tags: python, performance, dask

I'm finding that `dask.dataframe.rename` significantly increases compute times whenever the dataframe is being read from a parquet file:

```
In [1]: import dask.dataframe as dd
   ...: df = dd.demo.daily_stock('GOOG', '2008', '2010', freq='1s', random_state=1234)
   ...: 

In [2]: %time df.close.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 7.73 s, sys: 1.15 s, total: 8.88 s
Wall time: 3.5 s
Out[2]: 452.30345234893554

In [3]: %time df = df.rename(columns={col: col.upper() for col in df.columns}); df.CLOSE.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 8.06 s, sys: 1.21 s, total: 9.27 s
Wall time: 3.81 s

In [4]: df.to_parquet('df', compression='GZIP')
   ...: df = dd.read_parquet('df')
   ...: 

In [5]: %time df.CLOSE.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 4.14 s, sys: 729 ms, total: 4.87 s
Wall time: 2.1 s
Out[5]: 452.30345234893554

In [6]: %time df = df.rename(columns={col: col.lower() for col in df.columns}); df.close.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 9.72 s, sys: 1.89 s, total: 11.6 s
Wall time: 4.81 s
```

Notice that the differences are small on the original dataframe, but more than double on the parquet-based dataframe.

The problem is exaggerated on large datasets (~20-30GB) where I'm seeing `mean` computations go from seconds to multiple minutes.

Is this something inherent to parquet files that I'm not aware of, or is this a bug of some sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parquet is a column store.  Reading a single column from a parquet file can be much faster than reading the entire dataset.  When you do `df.close.mean().compute()` Dask notices that you have a `read_parquet` operation followed immediately by a column access operation and it can intelligently fuse them to something smarter like the following:

```
df = dd.read_parquet(filename, columns=['close'])
```

However, when you throw the `rename` operation in between the `read_parquet` call and the column access operation Dask.dataframe is not smart enough to realize that it can commute column access and renaming, so you end up reading in all the data from the parquet file, renaming the columns, and then throwing away all of the columns except for one.

This lack of ability to perform high-level reasoning about computations is precisely where databases or more high-level systems like Spark Dataframes  start to win out over Dask.dataframe.  At its core Dask is generally lower level, and so can do crazier computations, but loses the ability to do any but the most basic query optimization.

So in this case it's not the fact that `rename` is slowing things down, it's the fact that `rename` is throwing a wrench in a very simple optimization scheme.

Comment: If you really only want the one column, but want to rename it, you can specify the (original) columns to read_parquet as above, or select before rename as df['close'].rename(...).

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of rename method acts on each partition of the dataframe and it has an overhead that i believe is equivalent to `dd.rename`

Consider this:

```
In [45]: %time (dd.demo.daily_stock('GOOG', '2008', '2010', freq='1s',  
random_state=1234).repartition(npartitions=1).rename(columns = {col: 
col.upper() for col in df.columns}).CLOSE.mean().compute())
CPU times: user 11.7 s, sys: 4.65 s, total: 16.3 s
Wall time: 9.23 s
Out[45]: 450.46079905299979

In [46]: %time (dd.demo.daily_stock('GOOG', '2008', '2010', freq='1s',  
random_state=1234).repartition(npartitions=1).close.mean().compute())
CPU times: user 11.3 s, sys: 4.63 s, total: 15.9 s
Wall time: 8.8 s
Out[46]: 450.46079905299979
```

When partition is set to 1, rename overhead seems to be not as pronounced as in your example.

**Update 1: Adding Parquet Example**

```
In [103]: data =dd.read_parquet('df').repartition(npartitions=1).rename(columns = {'close':'ClOSE', 'high ':'HIGH', 'low':'LOW', 'open':'OPEN'})

In [104]: %time data.ClOSE.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 9.68 s, sys: 2.84 s, total: 12.5 s
Wall time: 5.72 s
Out[104]: 450.46079905299979

In [105]: data = dd.read_parquet('df').repartition(npartitions=1)

In [106]: %time data.close.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 9.37 s, sys: 2.56 s, total: 11.9 s
Wall time: 5.1 s
Out[106]: 450.46079905299979
```

**Update 2: Add columns explicitly**

Per Matt's answer above, avoiding reading all the columns of Parquet file would look like the following:

```
%time dd.read_parquet('df',columns =['close']).rename(columns = {'close':'CLOSE'}).CLOSE.mean().com
     ...: pute()
CPU times: user 4.65 s, sys: 801 ms, total: 5.45 s
Wall time: 2.71 s
```

which is similar to:

```
%time dd.read_parquet('df',columns =['close']).close.mean().compute()
CPU times: user 4.46 s, sys: 795 ms, total: 5.25 s
Wall time: 2.51 s
Out[110]: 450.46079905300002
```

**Aside**: rename + task scheduling has an overhead of ~`40ms` on a single partition of data on my machine:

```
In [114]: %timeit -n 3 dd.read_parquet('df',columns =['close']).repartition(npartitions=1).rename(columns = {
     ...: 'close': 'CLOSE'}).CLOSE.mean().compute()
3 loops, best of 3: 2.36 s per loop

In [115]: %timeit -n 3 dd.read_parquet('df',columns =['close']).repartition(npartitions=1).close.mean().compu
     ...: te()
3 loops, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop
```

Applied to something like 500 partitions, thats about 20 seconds. Just in case, this sort of thing is helpful in future.